# Best in Place Editor Clearing TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I am using the [Best in Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) editor to enable an inline text editor in my Rails app.

When I click on a best in place element, it shows an empty textarea instead of the current value of the text editor.  For example, if I have the text "Test Project" and click on the best in place editor, it sets the text to "&nbsp"  If I click out of the best in place area, though, it returns to the correct static text.

Here is a video of the bug:
https://youtu.be/xA18Odj47sc

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<%= best_in_place @collection, :name, :type => :textarea, :nil => @collection.name, :sanitize => false, :value => @collection.name %>
```

And this is what gets rendered on the page:

Before click:

```
      <span class="best_in_place" id="best_in_place_collection_1_name" data-url="/collections/introduction-to-product-design--3" data-object="collection" data-attribute="name" data-nil="Test Project" data-type="textarea" data-sanitize="false">Test Project</span>
```

After click:

```
<span class="best_in_place" id="best_in_place_collection_1_name" data-url="/collections/introduction-to-product-design--3" data-object="collection" data-attribute="name" data-nil="Test Project" data-type="textarea" data-sanitize="false">
      <form action="javascript:void(0)" style="display:inline">
          <textarea style="min-width: 193px; min-height: 66px; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
          <div style="position: absolute; display: none; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: 400; width: 206px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; padding: 4px 6px;">&nbsp;</div>  
      </form>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a bug because after I simplified the best in place text area to:

```
 <%= best_in_place @collection, :name, :type => :textarea %>
```

it seemed to work.  Perhaps something is currently wrong with setting a value.